# curl post for elasticsearch in python

Tags: python, curl

I have a curl POST to do for elasticsearch:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index/name" --data-binary "@file.json"
```

How can I do this in a python shell? Basically because i need to loop over many json files. I want to be able to do this in a for loop.

```
import glob
import os
import requests



def index_data(path):
    item = []
    for filename in glob.glob(path):
        item.append(filename[55:81]+'.json')
    return item

def send_post(url, datafiles):
    r = requests.post(url, data=file(datafiles,'rb').read())
    data = r.text
    return data

def main():
    url = 'http://localhost:9200/index/name'
    metpath = r'C:\pathtofiledirectory\*.json'
    jsonfiles = index_data(metpath)
    send_post(url, jsonfiles)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I fixed to do this, but is giving me a TypeError:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) http client :

```
import requests

files = ['file.json', 'file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json', 'file4.json']

for item in files:
    req = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/index/name',data=file(item,'rb').read())
    print req.text
```

From your edit, you would need :

```
for item in jsonfiles:
    send_post(url, item)
```

Comment: Thanks posted my code up top. Am receiving a TypeError that I can't figure out.

Comment: You need to loop through your `send_post` function see my edit. The `TypeError` you receive means that you specify array as `requests.post` arguments where it expects string

Comment: Got it, I needed to fix one more thing in how I was retrieving the file. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) library.

```
import requests
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

It is as simple as that.